# How to count number of items in queryset without count()

Tags: python, django

I'd like to count the number of items returned in my queryset. For example

`userdesigns = Design.objects.filter (desadder = user.id)`

I'd like to get the number of object returned **without** using count().

The reason is that I'm trying to speed up performance and reduce the number of database queries that I perform and I noticed that using count() pings the database, which I don't want. Considering I already pulled the complete lets of userdesigns, shouldn't there be a way to just count the number of items stored in that returned queryset?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> *len()*. A QuerySet is evaluated when you call len() on it. This, as you might expect, returns the length of the result list.
>
> Note: Don't use len() on QuerySets if all you want to do is determine the number of records in the set. It's much more efficient
>   to handle a count at the database level, using SQL's SELECT COUNT(*),
>   and Django provides a count() method for precisely this reason. See
>   count() below.

[Source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated)

So, if you call `len(userdesigns)` instead of `userdesigns.count()`, django will request all related data from the table in a single query. After that you can access all items of `userdesigns` variable, no additional queries will be made.

```
>>> m = Model1.objects.filter(desadder=1)
>>> len(m)
(0.000) SELECT "app1_model1"."id", "app1_model1"."desadder", "app1_model1"."test" FROM "app1_model1" WHERE "app1_model1"."desadder" = 1 ; args=(1,)
2
>>> m[0]
<Model1: Model1 object>
>>> m = Model1.objects.filter(desadder=1)
>>> len(m)
(0.000) SELECT "app1_model1"."id", "app1_model1"."desadder", "app1_model1"."test" FROM "app1_model1" WHERE "app1_model1"."desadder" = 1 ; args=(1,)
2
>>> m[0]
<Model1: Model1 object>
>>>
```

Comment: Oh interesting. So you're saying that instead of running my query above, instead I can just use `len()` from the get-go and all the items in `userdesigns` will come along for the ride?

Comment: Yes. I've added an example from django shell.

Comment: "The reason is that I'm trying to speed up performance and reduce the number of database queries that I perform" => then learn to use `Queryset.select_related` too.

Comment: Thanks @Riateche and also Bruno

Comment: Bear in mind that calling `len()` on a queryset fetches everything from the set into a Python list, meaning you might sacrifice one extra DB call for a large in memory list of objects. Its not always a bad thing, just a trade-off to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Riateche answered this, but if you didn't want to use len() or .count() directly on the QuerySet, you could return a values_list and use len() on it.

Django documentation says:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/

> A ValuesQuerySet is useful when you know you're only going to need
>   values from a small  number of the available fields and you won't need
>   the functionality of a model instance object.

I doubt this is any more speedy, but you could always time it and see. It could be useful if you only want to return a subset of the total available fields in a table.